# Java Oracle localhost database connection (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I am currently using this simple code to try to connect to my database on this computer (in Java)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {       

    String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    Class.forName(driverName);

    String serverName = "localhost";
    String mydatabase = "xe";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase; 

    String username = "scott";
    String password = "tiger";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
   }
 }
```

For some reason, I do not understand I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

I think these classes are in the ojdbc5.jar file? Im not quite sure how to fix this error so any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might succeed better if you load the **Oracle classes** instead of MySQL:

```
String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
Class.forName(driverName);


String serverName = "localhost";
String mydatabase = "xe";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + serverName + ":1521/" + mydatabase;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, im now using that but I still get this


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver


I will look into the other response I got to see if I can clear this up

Comment: you don't have JAR in classpath. simple.

Comment: would the jar be the odbc5.jar? and I would put it in the project folder where the .classpath is located?

Comment: @user828727, To make sure you have the class loaded, you can add an `import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;` to your code. Btw, you can find the class in the Oracle `classes12.jar` too.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I just added the jar by right clicking on the project-> properties-> java build path-> libraries and click external jars, still have errors.... but oh well lol

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you obtained this code, but it contains several mistakes:

- `String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";` is meant to be used for accessing MySQL databases. If you intend to access a MySQL instance, use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`; `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` will work, but it is retained for backward compatibility. If you intend to access an Oracle instance using the Type 4 driver, use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`; avoid using `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` as it has been deprecated and might not be available in the newer drivers (especially in the ones released for Oracle 11g).
- `String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;` implies that you want to connect to a MySQL instance. But you are talking about accessing Oracle. In such a case, the Oracle driver will simply not work, for it recognizes JDBC URLs of a certain format. For using the thin driver present in `ojdbc5.jar`/`ojdbc6.jar` to access a database using the Service name and port, you should use the [thin-style service name syntax](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10589/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA), as outlined in the Oracle JDBC Developer's Guide. Your eventual JDBC URL format should therefore be:

  - `jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//localhost:1521/xe` or
  - `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe` if you do not want to pass the username and password in the JDBC URL.

Comment: Your very correct, somehow I got some example code for the wrong server i want to connect to lol, mind pointing me in the right direction for some oracle examples?

Comment: Well, I think you should get started with the [JDBC trail from the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/). Most databases will do, for studying JDBC, so if you are learning JDBC for the first time, don't bother about reading database-specific tutorials. The only database specific items you would have to bother about as a beginner are the JDBC driver classes and the JDBC URL formats. Use the Oracle JDBC Developer's Guide as a *reference* (and not as a starter) for JDBC programming against Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses something called "Classpath" in order to locate classes often contained within JAR files (not always, though).

This "classpath" option is set via command line execution by using the --classpath or -cp option. You should call the java command with this option specifying the location of the JAR files you downloaded, containing the Oracle JDBC Driver.

If you're using an IDE, chances are this option can be set automatically by looking for options like "Libraries", "Modules" or Classpath itself, depending on your IDE. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: fyi this works 2 project-> properties-> java build path-> libraries and click external jars

Comment: As I said the options and menus depend on your IDE.

Comment: I see, eclipse here btw. Thanks for your help!